# Convert C#'s FileTimeUTC number to Date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, date-conversion

I am working with UTC string (130459385299470000) I need to convert this to some thing like Thursday 5 May 2014 15:17:00 in Javascript.

Any help with this will be much appreciated.

Thanks

RFD

Comment: what did you try to do?  we can't fix anything unless you show your work.

Answer (score 10):

There are some differences you'll have to contend with:

- A Windows file time uses an epoch of Jan 1, 1601.  A JavaScript `Date` uses Jan 1, 1970.  You will need to adjust the value accordingly.
- A Windows file time uses "ticks", which are 100-nanoseconds each.  A JavaScript `Date` uses milliseconds.  So there is a loss of precision.
- A Windows file time *might* not represent UTC.  It might represent time in some local time zone.  You will have to have an understanding of the source context to know whether or not the value is actually UTC.  If it's not, then you'll have to adjust it.
- A JavaScript `Date` is based on UTC, but will render it's output based on the local time zone of the machine that the code is running on. Often this is the end-user's web browser. You can use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) to render it as UTC, if that's the behavior you want.
- Since all JavaScript numbers are IEEE floating point numbers, when you start working with values that large, you can get rounding errors.  This can be avoided by truncating the string instead of dividing.

  ```
  var s = "130459385299470000";
  var t = +s.substring(0, s.length-4);
  var e = Date.UTC(1601,0,1);
  var dt = new Date(e + t);
  ```

Of course, the better thing to do would be to convert it to an ISO8601 timestamp in your C# code first, instead of passing the file time at all.

Comment: This should be an approved answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to a number, the number from microseconds to milliseconds, and create a JS Date object based on the UTC time:

```
var st = "130459385299470000";
var dt = new Date(parseInt(st, 10) / 1000);
```